# How to pass div ids to javascript at onload?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have an Html file like this:

```
<!doctype html>


<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/boxClass.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

/* lightBox class */

function box (id1,id2) {
    this.boxBackgroundDiv = document.getElementById (id1);
    this.boxWorkAreaDiv   = document.getElementById (id2);
}

lightBox.prototype.setBackgroundColor = function(c) {
    this.boxBackgroundDiv.style.backgroundColor = c;
    alert('Hello back');
};



function init (id1,id2)
{
   boxObj = new box (id1,id2);
   alert ("Hello");
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init('box1','box2')">
<div id="lightbox1" class="boxBackground">I am here</div>
<div id="lightbox2" class="boxWorkArea"><button onclick="boxObj.setBackgroundColor('Red')">I am here</button></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now when I call my init function the way it is in this code via it works fine. But if I do as below via window.onload, it does not work. its not able to get the div ids in this case. But I need div ids to crate objs for my class.

```
<!doctype html>


<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/boxClass.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

/* lightBox class */

function box (id1,id2) {
    this.boxBackgroundDiv = document.getElementById (id1);
    this.boxWorkAreaDiv   = document.getElementById (id2);
}

lightBox.prototype.setBackgroundColor = function(c) {
    this.boxBackgroundDiv.style.backgroundColor = c;
    alert('Hello back');
};



function init (id1,id2)
{
   boxObj = new box (id1,id2);
   alert ("Hello");
}
window.onload = init ("box1",box2);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="lightbox1" class="boxBackground">I am here</div>
<div id="lightbox2" class="boxWorkArea"><button onclick="boxObj.setBackgroundColor('Red')">I am here</button></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1) You are missing quotes around box2 parameter,

2) You are assigning the return value of init function (which here is a void) to window.onload handler.

You should assign the onload handler as below:

```
window.onload = function(){
 init ("box1","box2");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I knew this but I dont know why I did not try it before posting this question.